# Takes multiple attempts to connect 5GHz AC Wireless

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (dual boot with Windows 8.1)

Hardware: HP Spectre x360 - 13-4002dx

Network: Intel Wireless-AC 7265

Driver: iwlwifi

Driver Version: 3.16.0-56-generic

When I boot into Ubuntu (regardless of last boot being Windows/Ubuntu), it takes me several (over a dozen) attempts to authenticate to my wireless-AC router.  I have the password stored, so I just keep hitting connect over and over again (5-6 second delay between prompts).  Eventually it will connect.  This doesn't happen with Windows.  This also doesn't happen if I connect to the 2.4 GHz band on the same exact router - only with 5 GHz.

Like I said, it will eventually connect, but it is annoying to have to keep trying.  Any ideas what could be causing this, or how to fix it?

Comment: The driver version and associated firmware in later Ubuntu versions, 15.10 for example, is much better. Is upgrading feasible for you?

Comment: I'm relatively new to using linux still, so I opted for the apparently more stable and better supported 14.04 version.  There is no explicit reason I couldn't upgrade to 15.10, but it is important for me to have a stable system, as it is my primary OS on my primary machine.  I was hoping for an answer like "oh, I've seen that before; add this line to the ... file and it should fix it."  :-)

Comment: I will give you the suggested fixes but, at the end of the day, 15.10 has the latest driver and calls up the latest firmware. Please see my answer in a few minutes. I run 15.10 on four machines and find it perfectly stable.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Finally, Network Manager will default to ethernet if it's available. Please make your tests with the ethernet detached.

Next, I suggest you install the backports package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Now we need the latest firmware.

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode  /lib/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot and check:

```
dmesg | grep firmware
```

Ideally, the -15 firmware is loaded and performance is greatly improved.

If this helps, you will need to recompile every time Update Manager installs a later kernel, known as linux-image. After the requested reboot, recompile:

```
cd backports-20151120
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: I am in the US, and the output of 'sudo iw reg get' listed US.

Comment: I've tried all your other suggestions as well.  No apparent change, except when I did the modprobe stuff it wouldn't connect at all, to any band, so I ended up restarting.  I may take your suggestion and upgrade to 15.10.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: I will edit my answer further in a few minutes to add additional suggestions.

Comment: I stopped short of installing the backports package.  I did end up upgrading the OS - what a PITA.  I tried the friendly-looking "upgrade" from 14.04 to 15.04, which resulted in an inoperable system.  Then I installed 15.10 over the broken 15.04, which seemed to mostly work, except for some lightdm-related errors.  "Fixing" those errors resulted in another inoperable system, so I completely wiped the partitions, reset back to Windows boot manager, and started from scratch.  So far so good.  And hey, the 5GHz band does seem to be behaving a little better now.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Chili.  I'll definitely keep these in my back pocket and try them out if the wonky behavior returns.